# "Looking for a postdoc" ad inside a conference talk?

Tags: conference, job-search, presentation

I got my PhD one year ago; I am looking for a position (e.g., postdoc).
I am going to a fairly attended conference, and was pondering about how to make audience aware that I am on the market.

- An explicit, dedicated slide (maybe at the end)?
- A verbal statement?
- A caption on my T-shirt? :)

Would you find any of this appropriate? 
What would you advice me to do?

**EDIT** 
In case you think it's not a good idea, I'd be interested in knowing why. 
Otherwise, I'd be interested in any additional implementation advice (how to formulate that, or whatever comes to mind).

Comment: We can't hire you if we don't know who you are.

Comment: @JeffE Do you mean that apart from the *I am available*, there should be a slide containing biographical or personal information of some sorts?

Comment: I've even heard _advisors_ mentioning that their students are on the market ("... this other case was solved by my student Mr. X, who, by the way, is on the market right now ..."), so I wouldn't worry too much about it "not being a good idea".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't be shy about advertising. As you and Dave suggest, place it at the end, but you don't need to be very subtle about it. I've seen a number of talks where people advertise the fact that they're on the market, and everyone understands the need to do this. Presumably you're worried about it seeming desperate, but it isn't.

Comment: Au contraire, a little self-depricating humor could get a laugh, break the ice, and get a conversation going.

Answer (score 19):

I would add to the end of your conclusion a simple statement:

> By the way, I'm looking for a postdoc position.

I've seen it done before, and I don't think people minded.

A T-shirt could be a fun way of broaching the topic when talking to people.

Answer (score 2):

Be personal (if possible). Try to research the person or people that may be interested in you and approach them directly.